# Include section numbering in list from tocloft package

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices, tocloft

I want to include a list of appendices after my `ToC`, which I to some extent have managed, with this code:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
\parindent0mm
```

and by using the command

```
\listofappendices
```

after my `ToC` and

```
\appendices{*name of appendix*}
```

under the specific appendix section I want to include.

The problem is, that in my text, the appendices is numbered A.1, A.2 etc, but in my `tocloft` list, they only appear as "name of appendix".

Is there any way I can add the section numbering to my list?

Comment: Please, add a short, but complete example of code.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

As long as `\addcontentsline{...}{...}{#1}` is used there will be no numbering. The usual way is to use `\addcontentsline{...}{...}{\theappendices~#1}`, i.e. printing the appendix number before the title.

I hope, that the `appendix` package is not used as well, otherwise this would cause a conflict with the `appendices` environment.

The way `\appendices` (in the OP) was defined is incomplete, it does neither print the title in the text nor does it make any use of the `appendices` counter by incrementing. Since it is very likely that there might be references to the relevant appendix section I've decided to use `\refstepcounter{appendices}`.

The `\section*{#1 \theappendices}` is just for convenience and can be replaced by other typesetting 'eye-candy' at will.

Also use `\parindent=0em` rather than `\parindent=0mm`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{appendices}%
  \section*{#1 \theappendices}%
  \addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{\theappendices~ #1}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\parindent=0em

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendices

\blinddocument
\appendices{Foo One}
\appendices{Foo Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]